# import readline segfaults after import TVM on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, readline, pdb, tvm

I'm working with [TVM](https://github.com/dmlc/tvm), a deep learning compiler. In my workflow, it is useful to be able to use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, and drop into the debugger. However, `pdb.set_trace()` causes a segfault anytime after TVM has been imported.

My current setup is
- Ubuntu 16.04 (running on Windows Subsystem for Linux, but this happens on my native 16.04 machine too!)
- Python 3.6

This problem does not occur on Windows or Mac.

This problem only occurs when running a script from the commandline (i.e. `python3 minimum-reproducible-example.py`), not when running from the `python3` repl.

I've done some debugging with gdb, and narrowed it down: the error occurs when the `readline` package is imported.

Minimum reproducible example:

```py
import tvm
import readline
```

After debugging with gdb, I traced it to a specific line in cpython:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.   
PyModule_GetState (m=0x0) at Objects/moduleobject.c:558
558         if (!PyModule_Check(m)) {
```

In this case, `m` is `0x0`, which the function doesn't seem to expect.

If anyone could even just point me towards more useful ways to debug this, that would be helpful!

Comment: The best place for TVM based discussion is the [Discuss forums](https://discuss.tvm.ai)